# Bertrand's postulate for primes congruent to 1 modulo 4

Tags: elementary-number-theory

One should be able to show that there is a prime congruent to 1 modulo 4 between n and 2n for every sufficiently large n.  Does anyone know a reference for this with an explicit bound on how large n needs to be?  I would, of course, prefer it to be small.

Comment: Something here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62398/generalization-of-bertrands-postulate