# Find all n such that there exists a solution of $a^2 + b^2 = n!$ for positive integers $a, b, n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, sums-of-squares

I recently found this problem saying:

> Find all $n$ such that there exists a solution of $a^2 + b^2 = n!$ for positive integers $a, b, n$.

I first thought to show $n!$ will contain some prime of the form $4k+3$ odd number of times after some value $n_0$. Then I thought by Bertrand's postulate $n!$ (for $n >3$ ) contains at least one prime only once. If any of them is of the form $4k+3$ we would be done. But I failed to make any more progress.

Comment: Well, it should be easy enough to determine the answer, if you can't prove it.  As to a possible proof... There are versions of Bertrand's postulate for arithmetic progressions, see, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62398/generalization-of-bertrands-postulate)

Comment: I think n=2 is the only solution,but i still can't prove it.Can you give me some more hint?

Comment: $2$ is not the only solution.  There is one other small solution (bigger than $2$).  I don't know if the variants of Bertrand I mentioned are strong enough to prove the result or not, I did not try.

Comment: It is enough to prove that  if $ p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ and $p\ge 7$, then there is a prime $q \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ strictly between $p$ and $2p$. I don't know a proof.

Comment: [A proof is posted here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Factorial_which_is_Sum_of_Two_Squares) that $n$ must be $\leq6$.